# How to copy object from one shell to another shell?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, object, irb

You have two open IRB shells in separate terminal windows. The first shell has the following code already entered:

```
class Apple

  attr_reader :variety, :origin, :history
  def initialize(**args)
    @variety = args[:variety]
    @origin = args[:origin]
    @history = args[:history]
  end
end

apple = Apple.new(variety: 'Honeycrisp', origin: 'Minnesota', history: 'Introduction to Market: 1991')
```

The second shell has the following code already entered:

```
class Apple

  attr_reader :variety, :origin, :history
  def initialize(**args)
    @variety = args[:variety]
    @origin = args[:origin]
    @history = args[:history]
  end
end
```

Write the code in the shell(s) that copies an object apple from shell one to shell two. Bonus: write the solution without using external Ruby libraries.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Marshal](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Marshal.html) for that, in one terminal run.

```rb
Marshal.dump(apple)
```

Copy the string returned.

```rb
str = [copied from the other terminal]
apple = Marshal.load(str)
```

Comment: what will be the best way to shift string from one to another shell? what about through file? @javiyu

Comment: Anything that can transport the string, a socket, file, HTTP request between services, etc.

Comment: You would typically write your code in files which are loaded and reloaded in the shell with a autoloader. Moving code from one shell to another isn't actually something you do.